# C++ QT SQLite Best Practice

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I am building an app that writes data to a database and reads it.
I need to know the best way to go about doing it.
Firstly will it slow down my application setting up functions that open and close the database when they run?

```
void Inventory::insert(int item, double qnty, int loc)
{
CC_Number cn;
char result[100];   // array to hold the result.
strcpy(result,"INSERT INTO Inventory (Item_ID, Qnty , Loc_ID) Values (");
strcat(result,cn.int_to_char(1));
strcat(result,",");
strcat(result,cn.int_to_char(2));
strcat(result,",");
strcat(result,cn.int_to_char(3));
strcat(result,");");
db = new CC_Database("Inventory.sqlite");
db->query(result);
db->close();
}
```

Or should I open the database when the main window of the app opens and close the database when it is destroyed?

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
db = new CC_Database("Inventory.sqlite");
ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
db->close();
delete ui;
}
```

I started out with the second method, but hit a road block getting the db variable from the mainwindow class into other classes in order to run queries.
I am very new to C++ so if I have made a glaring mistake please be kind.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [singleton design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). This way the database would be opened when needed and accessible from everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

> Or should I open the database when the main window of the app opens and close the database when it is destroyed? […]

Yes, that will be the preferred method because there is simply no need to open and close a database connection all the time.

> I [… tried that] but hit a road block getting the db variable from the mainwindow class into other classes in order to run queries.

In the Qt SQL classes, there is a simple solution for this when you are only using a single database in your application: by creating an unnamed database connection, that connection will be used by default when you use `QSqlQuery::exec()` without specifying a connection ([manual ref](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#details)).

So you would indeed "open the database when the main window of the app opens and close the database when it is destroyed", like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) 
    : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {

    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE"); // QSqlDatabase
    db.setDatabaseName("Inventory.sqlite");

    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
    db->close();
    delete ui;
}
```

And then any code that wants to access the database with a query can simply look like this:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("INSERT INTO Inventory ...");
if(!query.exec()) {
    qWarning() << "ERROR: " << query.lastError().text();
}
```

For a full example of using SQLite this way under Qt, have a look at [QtSqlExample](https://github.com/vivaladav/BitsOfBytes/tree/master/howto-embed-database-in-application-with-sqlite-and-qt) or [QML SQL Example](https://github.com/tanius/qml-sql-example). (The latter is my own variant, using QML. The first uses QWidgets instead.)